# Posicionar um elemento sobre o outro

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
.lista-cartoneira h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.lista-cartoneira h2 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
}

.lista-cartoneira img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    margin: 12px;
}

.card-panel {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.col.s9.lista-cartoneira {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.botoes-cartoneira.row {
    height: 56px; 
    margin: 24px 0 24px 0;
}

.botoes-cartoneira.col {
    height: 56px; 
    text-align: center;
}

.atalhos-cartoneira.col i {
    margin-top: 43px;
}

.atalhos-cartoneira.col {
    height: 110px; text-align: center; color: white;
}

.item-total {
    width: 200%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 340px) {
    .col.s9.lista-cartoneira {
        width: 75%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .col.s9.lista-cartoneira {
        width: 220%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .lista-cartoneira h1 {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
    .lista-cartoneira h2 {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;">
                <div class="item-total">
                    <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3" style="width: 50%;">
                        <div class="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
                            <div class="row valign-wrapper">
                                <div class="col s3 lista-cartoneira" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrSKKu7oCCmPKDSTU6aSsZMfnUxrVImzv42-DDnAgVBmG54Szz" alt="" class="circle responsive-img">  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col s9 lista-cartoneira">
                                    <h1>ABC</h1>
                                    <h2>DEF</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3" style="width: 50%; float: right; margin-top: -136px;">
                    <div class="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
                        <div class="row valign-wrapper botoes">
                            <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #00b0ff;">
                                <i class="material-icons">phone</i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #ffb74d;">
                                <i class="material-icons">email</i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #757575;">
                                <i class="material-icons">place</i>
                            </div>
                             <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #00BFA5;">
                                <i class="material-icons">open_in_new</i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.botoes').hide();
                // DESLIZA 
                var inicialX;
                addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
                    var toqueobj = e.changedTouches[0];
                    inicialX = toqueobj.pageX;
                }, false);
                //
                addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }, false)
                //
                addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
                    var toqueobj = e.changedTouches[0];
                    var distancia = toqueobj.pageX - inicialX;
                    if(distancia < 0){
                        $('.botoes').show(100);
                        $('.botoes').css('position', 'relative');
                    }
                    if(distancia > 0){
                       $('.botoes').hide(100);

                    }
                }, false)
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tenho este html:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;">
                <div class="item-total">

                    <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3" style="width: 50%;">
                        <div class="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
                            <div class="row valign-wrapper">
                                <div class="col s3 lista-cartoneira" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                    <img src="img/user-profile.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img">  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col s9 lista-cartoneira">
                                    <h1>ABC</h1>
                                    <h2>DEF</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Quando o usuário desliza para esquerda, aparece os botões:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```
<div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3" style="width: 50%; float: right; margin-top: -136px;">
                        <div class="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
                            <div class="row valign-wrapper botoes">
                                <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #00b0ff;">
                                    <i class="material-icons">phone</i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #ffb74d;">
                                    <i class="material-icons">email</i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #757575;">
                                    <i class="material-icons">place</i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #00BFA5;">
                                    <i class="material-icons">open_in_new</i>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                   </div> 
                </div>
```

Até aí tudo bem, mas gostaria que quando aparecesse esses botões cobrisse toda a primeira imagem e ficasse somente os botões, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Não duplicados, é só para dar de exemplo. Que preenchesse toda a primeira div com os 4 botões. Logo, quando ele deslizasse novamente, esconde os botões e aparece a div novamente. Como poderia fazer isso?

**OBS:** Para testar os botões só deslizando com os dedos no pc ou no celular, o meu é touch por isso funciona.

Comment: Amigo primeiramente edite sua pergunta e coloque o código completo, incluindo a parte do Script para podermos simular o comportamento desse componente. Depois, se vc arrastar o elemento de cima todo "para fora" ele vai sumir e não vai ter como vc arrasta-lo novamente pois vc não vai conseguir mais clicar nele para arrastar...

Comment: @hugocsl editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara seu código tem alguns probleminhas com esses CSSs que vc colocou inline direto no style das tags. Basicamente tinha algumas propriedades desnecessárias, assim como algumas propriedade do grid do Materialize usadas de forma equivocada e tive que remove-las. Veja abaixo como ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código que usei para fazer a imagem acima, repare que deixei os CSSs direto na tag no style como vc fez, mas recomendo que vc coloque essas propriedades nas classes dos elementos correspondentes.

```js
$('.botoes').hide();
// DESLIZA 
var inicialX;
addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    var toqueobj = e.changedTouches[0];
    inicialX = toqueobj.pageX;
}, false);
//
addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}, false)
//
addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    var toqueobj = e.changedTouches[0];
    var distancia = toqueobj.pageX - inicialX;
    if(distancia < 0){
        $('.botoes').show(100);
        $('.botoes').css('position', 'relative');
    }
    if(distancia > 0){
       $('.botoes').hide(100);

    }
}, false)
```

```css
.lista-cartoneira h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.lista-cartoneira h2 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
}

.lista-cartoneira img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    margin: 12px;
}

.card-panel {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.col.s9.lista-cartoneira {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.botoes-cartoneira.row {
    height: 56px; 
    margin: 24px 0 24px 0;
}

.botoes-cartoneira.col {
    height: 56px; 
    text-align: center;
}

.atalhos-cartoneira.col i {
    margin-top: 43px;
}

.atalhos-cartoneira.col {
    height: 110px; text-align: center; color: white;
}

.item-total {
    width: 200%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 340px) {
    .col.s9.lista-cartoneira {
        width: 75%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .col.s9.lista-cartoneira {
        width: 220%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .lista-cartoneira h1 {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
    .lista-cartoneira h2 {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
    <div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; position: relative;">
        <div class="item-total">
            <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
                    <div class="row valign-wrapper">
                        <div class="col s3 lista-cartoneira" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrSKKu7oCCmPKDSTU6aSsZMfnUxrVImzv42-DDnAgVBmG54Szz"
                                alt="" class="circle responsive-img">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s9 lista-cartoneira">
                            <h1>ABC</h1>
                            <h2>DEF</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 " style="position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;">
            <div class="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
                <div class="row valign-wrapper botoes">
                    <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #00b0ff;">
                        <i class="material-icons">phone</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #ffb74d;">
                        <i class="material-icons">email</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #757575;">
                        <i class="material-icons">place</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #00BFA5;">
                        <i class="material-icons">open_in_new</i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```